# Raid 1 with Ubuntu live server ISO

Tags: 18.04

I'm trying to set up a RAID 1 Software using Ubuntu Server Live 18.04 following this guide:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWiXBCaBr_o

When i just Tried to add the first partition to the first device the option Create Software Raid (md) become Grayed Out and it Is impossible to configire any RAID.

I'm really dont understand where i'm wrong. I seem to follow the guide on that link....

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote a guide on this and posted it to Reddit. You need to use the "alternate" server iso, not the standard which doesn't have RAID functionality. Here's the link to the [guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/blxflv/bootable_software_raid/), which can be used for RAID 0/1/5/10.

Comment: Tanks. Just a question if i use the GPT Disk over BIOS the biosgrub partition is part of the raid or is out?